# Is "fast" an adverb or an adjective in "She wanted her car to go fast"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> She wanted her car to go fast.

Is the word 'fast' is an adjective or an adverb? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is an adverb.

When in doubt, try substituting other words (adjectives and adverbs) and see which is a better fit:

> She wanted her car to go quickly.
>
> She wanted her car to go smoothly.